# Create bash script to create yaml files from existing linux etc/hosts files

Tags: bash, yaml, hosts

I'm new to scripting but have been tasked with creating yaml files from existing Linux /etc/hosts files. Using a hosts file here:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost
192.168.1.2    host1
192.168.1.3    host2
192.168.1.4    host3
192.168.1.5    host4
```

..to create yaml files that look like this:

```
host_entries:
  host1:
    ip: '192.168.1.2'
  host2:
    ip: '192.168.1.3'
  host3:
    ip: '192.168.1.4'
  host4:
    ip: '192.168.1.5'
```

I know there is more than one way to reach a desired solution. But I'm not quite sure how to script this in a way to get the correct format. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? Please show your work first, then ask for community help.

Comment: I haven't used it before, but `awk` could do it right from bash. You just need to make some research by yourself

Comment: YAML files that *look like* that, or YAML files that *parse equivalently to* that? Since YAML is a superset of JSON, one could easily use `jq` for the task.

Comment: To be clear, using `jq` will give you a strong guarantee of syntactically correct output -- so will a YAML module written to the spec in Python or a similar language. Anything you do with native tools (be it `bash` itself or `awk` or similar) will have no such guarantees.

Comment: @MikeVelazco, since `awk` is its own separate language, one could just as easily say that Python could do it right from bash. :)

Comment: My apologies for not showing work. I had already created a script to remove certain entries within the hosts file and then output that file. However I was told the file needed to be in yaml format and since I have no experience with yaml I wasn't sure if there was a better way to do this. For example some of what has been said here using awk, j q, python, etc. Thanks for the responses so far. I will do some more research.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you're right. I tought of `awk` as a tool, not as a language (what it really is) but I just remembered that this is the target of this language. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Following up on the distinction I was making earlier between *looking like* your given output and *parsing equivalent to* your given output, any program that's compliant with the YAML specification will treat a file with the following contents -- which are simultaneously valid YAML and valid JSON -- the exact same way as your described target output: `{"host_entries": {"host4": {"ip": "192.168.1.5"}, "host3": {"ip": "192.168.1.4"}, "host2": {"ip": "192.168.1.3"}, "host1": {"ip": "192.168.1.2"}}}`

Answer (score 6):

Easy and wrong (not strongly guaranteed that output will be valid YAML for all possible inputs):

```
{
  printf 'host_entries:\n'
  while read -r -a line; do
    [[ ${line[0]} ]] || continue             # skip blank lines
    [[ ${line[0]} = "#"* ]] && continue      # skip comments
    [[ ${line[0]} = 127.0.0.1 ]] && continue # skip localhost

    set -- "${line[@]}" # assign words read from line to current argument list
    ip=$1; shift        # assign first word from line to ip
    for name; do        # iterate over other words, treating them as names
      printf "  %s:\n    ip: '%s'\n" "$name" "$ip"
    done
  done
} </etc/hosts >yourfile.yaml
```

...for something that's shorter and wrong-er, see edit history (prior version also worked for your sample input, but couldn't correctly handle blank lines, comments, IPs with more than one hostname, etc).

Given your exact host file as input, this emits:

```
host_entries:
  host1:
    ip: '192.168.1.2'
  host2:
    ip: '192.168.1.3'
  host3:
    ip: '192.168.1.4'
  host4:
    ip: '192.168.1.5'
```

Comment: Thanks for this it gave me some good ideas about how to generate yaml from structured input.

Comment: I did specify that this answer was "wrong" for good reasons. Better to use a tool like jq (all valid JSON is also valid YAML).

Comment: Totally agree :-) things have moved on since this question.